# Regex: match text between 2 items

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

How would I match the code below to get two strings:

1. title to the third closing a tag
2. 2nd title to the 6th closing a tag.(and so on...3rd title to the 9th closing a tag...etc)

Here is the string to be matched:

```
title
<a></a>
content here
<a></a>
text...
<a></a>
text...
title 
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
```

I tried using .* but this captured the text from the title to the last a tag.

Comment: I hope you aren't parsing HTML using regexes! http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/188

Comment: Is that a 6-fold nested anchor element? What the heck is this page doing?

Comment: @Matthew, the code format never changes so I don't see anything wrong with using regex to parse html in this case...

Comment: "Never changes", until it does. I sometimes extract data from HTML using regexes, but usually it's just as easy to fire up a proper parser, and grab the bit(s) you want.

Comment: like @MatthewSchinckel says, you could do this job much faster using something like beautifulSoup or lxml packages.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza really? I am using lxml for this project, how would that work with lxml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from re import findall, DOTALL

text = '''
title
<a></a>
content here
<a></a>
text...
<a></a>
text...
title 
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
'''
print findall(r'title.*?</a>.*?</a>.*?</a>', text, DOTALL)
```

gives

```
['title\n<a></a>\ncontent here\n<a></a>\ntext...\n<a></a>', 'title \n<a></a>\n<a></a>\n<a></a>']
```

you can also use

```
print findall(r'title(?:.*?</a>){3}', text, DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally `*` is greedy, while `*?` is reluctant. Try replacing `.*` with `.*?`.

Comment: .*? will only get from title to the first </a> that follows it

Comment: Yes and hence you can apply it (either sequentially or nested) thrice to get your result. Also Matthew Schinckel's second comment might come in handy.